# Is it possible to have mutable binding and destructuring simultaneously?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, destructuring, mutable, borrow-checker

The folllowing code works as expected ([demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aec80b1cbeb4e7c5caae6c1720779f64)) but this requires two nested `match {}` which I want to replace with just one.

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
use std::collections::hash_map::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct NormalTransaction(f64);

//  only normal transaction can be disputed.. BY DESIGN
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct DisputeTransaction(NormalTransaction);

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
enum Transaction {
    Normal(NormalTransaction),
    Dispute(DisputeTransaction),
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = HashMap::new();
    m.insert(1, Transaction::Normal(NormalTransaction(100.0)));
    
    println!("before: {:#?}", m);
    
    match m.get_mut(&1) {
        Some(t) => match t {
            Transaction::Normal(normal) => {
                *t = Transaction::Dispute(DisputeTransaction(normal.clone()));
            }   
            _ => {}, // NA
        }
        _ => {}, // NA
    }
    
    println!("after: {:#?}", m);
}
```

Replacing the two `match{}` with just one, as follows:

```rust
    match m.get_mut(&1) {
        Some(t @ Transaction::Normal(normal)) => {
            *t = Transaction::Dispute(DisputeTransaction(normal.clone()));
        }
        _ => {}, // NA
    }
```

but it does not work, saying ([demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=53729db837f5828f6d41dec99ddaabc2)):

```
error: borrow of moved value
  --> src/main.rs:24:14
   |
24 |         Some(t @ Transaction::Normal(normal)) => {
   |              -^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------^
   |              |                       |
   |              |                       value borrowed here after move
   |              value moved into `t` here
   |              move occurs because `t` has type `&mut Transaction` which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0382]: borrow of moved value
  --> src/main.rs:24:38
   |
24 |         Some(t @ Transaction::Normal(normal)) => {
   |              ------------------------^^^^^^-
   |              |                       |
   |              |                       value borrowed here after move
   |              value moved here
   |
   = note: move occurs because value has type `&mut Transaction`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
help: borrow this field in the pattern to avoid moving the value
   |
24 |         Some(ref t @ Transaction::Normal(normal)) => {
   |              +++
```

Is it possible to do the mutable binding and destructuring in single match case?

Comment: I'd guess the answer is 'no', with the `@` destructuring. At least that's my first impression, I honestly haven't known about the `@` before :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do it using a single match, but it doesn't look that bad if you use `if let`s instead of matches:

```rust
if let Some(t) = m.get_mut(&1) {
    if let Transaction::Normal(normal) = t {
        *t = Transaction::Dispute(DisputeTransaction(normal.clone()));
    }   
}
```

Once [let-chains](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2497-if-let-chains.html) lands I believe you should also be able to write

```rust
if let Some(t) = m.get_mut(&1) && let Transaction::Normal(normal) = t {
    *t = Transaction::Dispute(DisputeTransaction(normal.clone()));
}
```

Comment: Yes. That is what I have written after posting my question. This seems to be better especially because I dont care about the `else` case in both of the match expressions. So less code!

Comment: BTW, did you forget the second `let` in the *let-chains* code? or it's not required?

Comment: @Nawaz I just forgot, fixed.

Comment: In the absence of a better answer, I'm accepting this one now!